# How I specific string or number from a file?

Tags: c++

The issue is I've this file but I don't how obtain the string or numbers on it without quotes or commas ,and put it in auxiliar variable,

```
"string one" , 2500:25670, (0.676,-2.43)
"string two",259: 8765 , ( 12.22 , -7.56 )
```

For the moment I wrote this code:

```
string filename = getFilename(); //function to get filename
string line;
string data;

ifstream file;
file.open(filename.c_str(),ios::in);
if (!file.is_open())
{
  error(ERR_CANT_OPEN_FILE);
}
else
{

  while(getline(file,line))
  {

   bases.push_back(tempBases));
  }
}
```

Comment: Read up on [parsing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing).

Comment: Search the internet for "c++ read file CSV text" or "C++ read file comma separated text".  There are already tooo many similar posts on StackOverflow.

Comment: Hint:  `std::getline(file, text, ',')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the loop of reading file line by line:

```
while(getline(file,line))
{
// parse line to a token of strings with comma delimiter and assign each token  to variables or put to the vector 
}
```